# LeetCode 310: Minimum Height Trees

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

Posting my code for a LeetCode problem, if you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

### Problem

For an undirected graph with tree characteristics, we can choose any node as the root. The result graph is then a rooted tree. Among all possible rooted trees, those with minimum height are called minimum height trees (MHTs). Given such a graph, write a function to find all the MHTs and return a list of their root labels.

#### Format

The graph contains n nodes which are labeled from 0 to n - 1. You will be given the number n and a list of undirected edges (each edge is a pair of labels).

You can assume that no duplicate edges will appear in edges. Since all edges are undirected, [0, 1] is the same as [1, 0] and thus will not appear together in edges.

#### Example 1 :

```
Input: n = 4, edges = [[1, 0], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

        0
        |
        1
       / \
      2   3 

Output: [1]
```

#### Example 2 :

```
Input: n = 6, edges = [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [4, 3], [5, 4]]

     0  1  2
      \ | /
        3
        |
        4
        |
        5 

Output: [3, 4]
```

#### Note:

According to the definition of tree on Wikipedia: “a tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path. In other words, any connected graph without simple cycles is a tree.”
The height of a rooted tree is the number of edges on the longest downward path between the root and a leaf.

#### Code

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
        using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;

        static const std::vector<int> findMinHeightTrees(
            const int n,
            const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& edges
        ) {
            std::vector<int> buff_a;
            std::vector<int> buff_b;
            std::vector<int>* ptr_a = &buff_a;
            std::vector<int>* ptr_b = &buff_b;

            if (n == 1) {
                buff_a.emplace_back(0);
                return buff_a;
            }

            if (n == 2) {
                buff_a.emplace_back(0);
                buff_a.emplace_back(1);
                return buff_a;
            }

            std::vector<Node> graph(n);

            for (const auto& edge : edges) {
                graph[edge[0]].neighbors.insert(edge[1]);
                graph[edge[1]].neighbors.insert(edge[0]);
            }

            for (ValueType node = 0; node < n; ++node) {
                if (graph[node].isLeaf()) {
                    ptr_a->emplace_back(node);
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                for (const auto& leaf : *ptr_a) {
                    for (const auto& node : graph[leaf].neighbors) {
                        graph[node].neighbors.erase(leaf);

                        if (graph[node].isLeaf()) {
                            ptr_b->emplace_back(node);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (ptr_b->empty()) {
                    return *ptr_a;
                }

                ptr_a->clear();
                std::swap(ptr_a, ptr_b);
            }
        }

    private:
        static const struct Node {
            std::unordered_set<ValueType> neighbors;
            const bool isLeaf() {
                return std::size(neighbors) == 1;
            }
        };
};
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-height-trees/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-height-trees/discuss/)
- [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A triply nested loops always look scary. Especially with `while (true)`.

First thing first, trust yourself. The leaf node (and the `ptr_a` contains only leafs) has only one neighbour. The

```
for (const auto& node : graph[leaf].neighbors)
```

loop is effectively

```
auto& node = graph[leaf].neighbors.begin();
```

Second, no naked loops please. And more functions please. The

```
for (const auto& leaf : *ptr_a)
```

prunes leaves from the tree. Factor it out into a `prune_leaves` function, which would return a set (technically a vector) of the new leaves:

```
leaves = prune_leaves(leaves, graph);
```

Third, the outer loop shall naturally terminate when less than 3 leaves remain.

Finally, separate IO from the business logic. That said, a code along the lines of

```
    graph = build_graph();
    leaves = collect_leaves(graph);
    while (leaves.size() < 3) {
        leaves = prune_leaves(leaves, graph);
    }
    return leaves;
```

would win my endorsement. Notice how `ptr_a` and `ptr_b` - which are not the most descriptive names - disappear.